# Updating previous fragment from current fragment

Tags: android

I have two fragments called fragmentA and FragmentB. I can navigate from FragmentA to FragmentB by adding FragmentA to back-stack. Then I do some work on FragmentB and according to changes done on FragmentB, FragmentA  should be updated when I go back to FragmentA by pressing back button. Is there anyway to achieve this scenario?

Comment: code your update function and call it in OnResume of Fragment A. Please check whether you come from Fragment B before call the function because onResume will calls in other case too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it through the `Activity` which contains both `Fragments` implementing `callbacks`.

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method with the data you want to update in FragmentA in the activity and then get the data to fragmentA in onResume o something

```
//method in activity with the data to set
 public void setData(recieve data to be set)
 {
  //data you want to show in FragmentA;
  }
```

From fragmentB setData

```
  ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setData(send some data);
```

Create on more method in Activity which gives you the data you set
and then from fragmentA getData()

```
   ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getData(send some data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalBroadcastManager` for same. Register it on Attach and Detach of `Fragment` where you need to update like below code.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
            _onProfileUpdate,
            new IntentFilter(UserDefault.broadcastProfileUpdate));

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(
            _onProfileUpdate);
}
```

Create Handle in Your Fragment..

```
  private BroadcastReceiver _onProfileUpdate = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        setUpBasicInfo();
    }
};
```

And whenever need to update that fragment, simply invoke listener from other fragment. You can also pass required parameter in intent.

```
    Intent in = new Intent(UserDefault.broadcastProfileUpdate);
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).sendBroadcast(in);
```

Here, `UserDefault.broadcastProfileUpdate` is some static string or let say key.